# Checkboxes in Webform Custom Composite Table

Tags: webforms

I've been testing Drupal 9 and Webform 6.2.0-beta2. After researching a few hours, my understanding is that the current Webform doesn't support checkboxes in custom composite fields tables. Is that correct?

For instance, a field type "checkbox" with multiple options like "red, yellow, blue, and black". Once the form processes, these options don't appear on the page.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@see [Issue #3216923: Radios or Checkboxes inside Composite not saved](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3216923)